# How to install a guest OS in a minimal installation of Centos using KVM?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7

KVM newbie here, so be tolerant plz. I am trying to install a guest OS in a minimal installation of Centos7. I've been looking for tutorials around the web but all seem to be using a graphical host with VMM (Virtual Machine manager).

My minimal server does not have a graphical interface and obviously no VMM installed. So, how do I install a guest in host with no graphical interface ? What is the cli alternative for VMM? How am I supposed to render the graphical installation wizard ?

My intention here is to get the big picture of the entire process. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have a workstation? A laptop?

Comment: You may also find it helpful to read [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/chap-Virtual_machine_installation.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to figure it out. Follow these simple steps to install a VM in a minimal installation of CentOS 6.6 :

```
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 1.- install all these
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo yum groupinstall "Virtualization Platform" "Virtualization Tools"
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install python-virtinst
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install bridge-utils
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 1.a- dd image from CD-ROM
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/usr/share/CentOS-6.6.iso
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 2.- start this
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo service libvirtd start
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo chkconfig libvirtd on
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 3.- modify eth0 and create network bridge file
 [acool@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
 DEVICE=eth0
 HWADDR=90:2B:34:10:25:C0
 TYPE=Ethernet
 UUID=c74e1b53-a135-4573-ac74-8fd00b06a7ea
 ONBOOT=yes
 NM_CONTROLLED=no
 BRIDGE=br0
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
 DEVICE=br0
 TYPE=Bridge
 BOOTPROTO=static
 ONBOOT=yes
 IPADDR=192.168.1.45
 NETMASK=255.255.255.0
 GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
 DNS1=4.2.2.2
 DNS2=4.2.2.1
 DNS3=8.8.8.8
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 4.- restart networking
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo service network restart
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 5.- put all these parameters in a file
 [acool@localhost ~]$ cat virt-install.sh
 sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system \
 -n vm20 \
 -r 1024 \
 --vcpus=2 \
 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm20.img,size=12 \
 -c /usr/share/CentOS-6.6.iso \
 --graphics vnc \
 --noautoconsole \
 --os-type linux \
 --accelerate \
 --network=bridge:br0 \
 --hvm
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 6.- create VM !!
 [acool@localhost ~]$ ./virt-install.sh

 Starting install...
 Allocating 'vm20.img'                                            |  12 GB     00:00
 Creating domain...                                               |    0 B     00:00
 Domain installation still in progress. You can reconnect to
 the console to complete the installation process.
 [acool@localhost ~]$
 [acool@localhost ~]$ # 7.- make sure it's running
 [acool@localhost ~]$ sudo virsh list --all
  Id    Name                           State
 ----------------------------------------------------
  1     vm20                           running
  [acool@localhost ~]$
  [acool@localhost ~]$
  [acool@localhost ~]$ # In another computer, open Virtual Machine Manager and connect to 192.168.1.45 and install linux in vm20  :)
```

Comment: About to use your guide to try setting up a VM under CentOS 7 - will let you know how it goes!

Comment: python-virtinst is no longer in the RHEL 7 repos, and is now virt-install.  https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/2956-virtual-machines

Comment: I couldn't get the domain created till editing the qemu.conf file and setting user and group to root.   https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10608

Answer (score 1):

KVM (or, rather, qemu, which provides the emulated devices inside the VM) can provide an emulated keyboard/mouse/screen over VNC.  That will allow you to interact with the VM's console as though it were a physical machine you were sitting in front of.